# HTML to fill up bottom row first - Aesthetic reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is that possible to CSS or any method to display text starting from bottom row first and moving up to higher row as it goes on. Example:

- Row 1 Txt4    // ... ...
- Row 2 Txt3    //  the list goes on or leave empty and stops at row 3 if no more text to fill up
- Row 3 Txt2    //  the list goes on or leave empty and stops at row 4 if no more text to fill up
- Row 4 Txt1    // this line fills up first

This is NOT to rearrange mysql output nor to resort the order by ascending/descending of any sort. It's just simply forcing the HTML to fill up the most bottom row first for aesthetic reason. All Txt outputs are PHP dynamic. To make it simple, can we just assume the outputs are Txt1, Txt2, Txt3, Txt4.  As these are the final outputs and they involve few other hundred lines which i guess they are not relevant. Hope i have explained it well.

Comment: yes, if the rows are fixed.

Comment: separate rows or paragraphs ? what happen when one row is longer than one line (like when user is zooming text for example) ?

Comment: My response is as follows with @Ed Cottrell. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop through your data in reverse?  Something like this:

```
$max = count($data);
for($row = $max; $row >= 0; $row--) {
    echo "<p>Some HTML here".$data[$row]."</p>";
}
```

Edit: You can, of course, do the same thing in jQuery; just build the table or list in reverse, using the same basic logic.

Comment: Your code reverses the outputs and becomes "Tac", "Taog", "Riget" (Not Cat, Goat, Tiger). Perhaps @ mikakun was right. I guess it should have been a paragraph reversal? My php will echo $_Animals.'<br />'; which will produce those 3 animals in 3 lines. My objective is not to reverse the output given, but just for HTML aesthetic reason and filling bottoms-up as it goes. Thanks for that. I'm not coding literated, so all helps are really appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  This code will not flip words around, like Cat -> Tac.  Instead, if you start with `array('Cat', 'Goat', 'Tiger')`, it will produce Tiger, Goat, and then Cat, on three lines.  Is your goal to get a certain order (e.g., Tiger, Goat, then Cat), or is it to get items in a certain place on the screen (i.e., Tiger at the bottom, then Goat right above it, etc., only going as high as needed)?

Comment: The latter. That's right. It's just a preference for screen. Not intending to change whatever the array outputs. Purely doing this to fit the tight space i can squeeze for dynamic outputs. Not knowing how many lines the output in advance (dynamic) and i have more room to play on the top, therefore stacking from bottom will give me this advantage. It would otherwise cause overflow onto my img. Thanks.